# returning nested data in fastapi + pydantic v2 + sqlalchemy (orm_mode deprecated)

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic, pydantic-v2

Using SQLAlchemy 1 and pydantic v1, it used to be possible to return models that had reverse relationships. For example, you could return a School and all the programs associated with that school.

You would create a pydantic schema like this:

```
class CompanyAndProgramsSchema(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(..., min_length=1, max_length=50)
    company_type_id: int
    programs: list[ProgramSchema] # Where ProgramSchema is just a simple schema for Programs
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

If you had two SQLalchemy models (this is sqlalchemy 2 nonetheless, but same applies), that looked like this:

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company"
    
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    company_type_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("company_type.id",  ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=True)
    company_type: Mapped[CompanyType] = relationship("CompanyType", back_populates="companies")
    programs: Mapped[list["Program"]] = relationship("Program", back_populates="company")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Company={self.name}>"

class Program(Base):
    __tablename__ = "program"
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(200), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("company.id", ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=True)
    company: Mapped[Company] = relationship("Company", back_populates="programs")
```

Assuming you used the above pydantic schema, you could return something that looked like this by simply using the Company model:

```
{
    "name": "EC",
    "company_type_id": 1,
    "programs": [
        {
            "name": "PIA24",
            "company_id": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "PIA23",
            "company_id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, pydantic 2 has deprecated orm_mode = True and replaced it with from_attributes. However, when returning the data, it completely skips the list of associated programs, and looks like this:

{
"id": 1,
"name": "Harvard",
"company_type_id": 1,
}

Now due to SQLalchemy queries being lazy, if nothing attempts to access the data, it simply wont load. My understanding is that from_orm = True made sure the data actually was read.

My solution (I'm hoping there is a better way?) is that I manually use the pydantic model_validate() from the schema which seems to trigger the query and the associated relationships. This is what an endpoint might look like:

```
@router.get("/company/{company_id}")
def get_company(company_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db), response_model=CompanyAndProgramsSchema):
    db_company = db.query(Company).filter(Company.id == company_id).first()
    qs = CompanyAndProgramsSchema.model_validate(db_company)
return qs
```

My question is therefore: Am I missing something, is there no better way to make sure nested relationships are included when combining pydantic 2 and sqlalchemy?

Comment: You put `response_model` in the function signature, it should be in the decorator arguments.

Comment: You're exactly right, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you.